# How Can we compare 2 Cells in an Excel Sheet and find what is the difference between them...?

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

Can someone help me with this query...?

Q - How Can we compare 2 Cells in an Excel Sheet and find what is the difference between them…?

Example- 
I have 2 cells with "**Cepa Sneaker**" and  "**Cepa**"...I would like to Compare them and get an output of Just "**Sneaker**"...Because that is the only difference between those 2 cells

Comment: You need to give more examples.  For instance, if the two cells contained `"abcxyb"` and `"bxz"`, what should the result be?  (Or, a bit closer to your existing example, what do you expect as a difference between `"Cepa Sneaker"` and `"epa"`?)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, there are numerous ways one could interpret your request, which is unclear without more than one example.  The simplest interpretation is illustrated in the image:

[image: example]